# Access all local gits

Tags: git

I made the dumbest mistake and deleted my folder containing an application on my machine and it wasn't yet pushed to my github. I do however remember making local commits.

Is there a way I can see all my local repos?

I have an iMac btw

Comment: depends on you file system. No for linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Git repository for a project is normally stored within the project in a directory named `.git`. If you deleted the entire directory, you would have deleted the Git directory as well. However, if the Git repository were outside of the directory you deleted (for example, the directory you deleted was part of a larger project, or you had pushed to a different local repository) then it may still exist.

Git repositories are directories named either `.git` within a working repository, or named something like `myrepository.git` if they are bare. So if you search for all directories that contain `.git` in their name, you should find all of your local Git repositories. How you search for filenames depends on your platform; use locate, or spotlight, or find, or something of the sort depending on your platform and setup.